# How to make addEventListener stream continuously on button submit

Tags: javascript, html, fetch, addeventlistener

I am trying to stream a list of json objects from my servers endpoint to my frontend using javascript and html. Below is my code. Currently addEventListener works fine when I click my form button (HTML also added below for reference). Heres my problem:

The list of objects my server endpoint returns is a single list which is continuously having objects appended to the list. So I want my front end to refresh automatically every second to show the latest version. And so I am finding a way for my addEventListener to rerun the function each time after clearing the HTML it is pushing. Currently, I have to click on my button to achieve that and the previously pushed HTML is not getting cleared either. So each time I click on the button, I am getting all the existing HTML displayed as many times as I have clicked the button (old versions) plus the latest version of my endpoint data.

The solution I want to achieve is to be able to click on my start stream button once, and have the function run every X seconds after clearing the older data each time to only show the latest list returned by fetch.

```js
const startStream = document.querySelector('form')
const messageOne = document.querySelector('#message-1')

startStream.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()

  messageOne.textContent = 'Streaming...'

  function fetchData() {
    fetch('http://localhost:1337/dashboard')
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw Error('ERROR')
        }
        response.json().then(events => {
            events.forEach(event => {
              const html = `<div class="event">
                    Event: ${event.name}
                </div>
                `
              let div = document.createElement('div');
              div.setAttribute("id", "app");
              div.innerHTML = html;
              document.body.appendChild(div);

            })
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
          })
      })
  }
  fetchData()
});
```

```html
<h1>Dashboard</h1>

<form>
  <button>Start Stream</button>
</form>

<p id="message-1"></p>
```

Comment: 1) you dont need an event listener, you need a click event to setInterval() , you then need it to call your fetch request, then instead of appending the data just changing the data.  2) it also depends on what you are fetching from so you can determine if you are getting the latest feed, are you in control of the data? if not is there a timestamp added to the data?

Comment: @Danimal Makes sense. Can you share an example usage of click event with setInterval with me? Also, what function can I use to change the data instead of appending it? I do have control over the data I am sending. Each fetch returns the latest complete version of the feed so it is supposed to completely replace the previous fetch as that data becomes stale. It is not additive feed. And yes, each object in the list returned has timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

Is the question just how to run a function every X seconds? If so, the function you're looking for is `setInterval`, which is like `setTimeout` but it continues running over and over. For example:

```
setInterval( () => console.log("hello"), 100 )
```

will log "hello" once every 100ms

Comment: Thanks. I can start working with that. But in my code the way I am currently pushing HTML from the Javascript, I also need all that HTML to get cleared and reset each time the function works. Or else, each time the function runs, my HTML gets appended instead of replacing the existing data.

Also, do i need to wrap just my fetchData function in setInterval or is there a different way for me to implement it in my code?

Answer (score 0):

This is a detailed example but try this approach it may work for you ***any corrections will be great***:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Repeating Event example</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <button id="start-stream-btn">Start Streaming</button>
        <p id="message-section"></p>
        <div id="app-data-div"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            var streamButton = document.getElementById("start-stream-btn");
            var messageContainer = document.getElementById("message-section");
            var appDataContainer = document.getElementById("app-data-div");

            function handleFetchError(appDataContainerRef, messageContainerRef) {
                messageContainerRef.innerText = "There was an Error fetching data!";
                // optional clear previous data or leave it by commenting the line below
                appDataContainerRef.innerHTML = "";
            }
            // Define the function that fetches our data
            function fetchData(appDataContainerRef, messageContainerRef, timerRef) {
                fetch('http://localhost:1337/dashboard')
                    .then(response => {
                        if (!response.ok) {
                            throw Error('ERROR')
                        }
                        response.json().then(events => {
                            events.forEach(event => {
                                // Create your string here with a loop
                                const htmlString = `<div class="event">
                                    Event: ${event.name}
                                    </div>`;
                                // Set your string here - replacing any previous
                                appDataContainerRef.innerHTML = htmlString;
                            })
                        })
                            .catch(error => {
                                console.log(error);
                                handleFetchError(appDataContainerRef, messageContainerRef);
                                // optional clear timer on error, you can comment this out if you want the timer to continue
                                clearInterval(timerRef);
                            });
                    }).catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);
                        handleFetchError(appDataContainerRef, messageContainerRef);
                        // optional clear timer on error, you can comment this out if you want the timer to continue
                        clearInterval(timerRef);
                    });
            }
            var timerRef;
            // Attach event listener to your button
            streamButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault(); //if it is in a form or if you have any form on your current page
                messageContainer.innerText = "Streaming...";
                timerRef = setInterval(function () {
                    // check and clear your timer before adding another timer here on click
                    if (!!timerRef) clearInterval(timerRef);
                    fetchData(appDataContainer, messageContainer, timerRef);
                }, 1000); // X seconds intervals i.e. for now 1s = 1000ms
            });

        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. This does something very similar to what I already had:
The event.name replaces the previous event.name each time so I am only seeing the most recent one instead of seeing all. Basically, I want to set it up so that on each fetch, all the event.names show up from the list returned which replace all the event.names from the previous fetch. And I've also noticed your example code starts the actual streaming only after I click on the Start Stream button a couple of times. Up till then it shows a static event.name. Not sure why that could be happening.

Comment: @Slash try checking the request on your network tab on your browser, it may be taking some time before it responds with the first result from the backend. Try clicking once and wait for some short time you see the behaviour. (I did not test with a backend)

Comment: Just checked that the backend is returning the data immediately. Also, any suggestion on how I can tweak this so that event.names shows up for each item in the list returned instead of just the most recently added item?

Comment: Store the current htmlString as a global variable, then instead of  `const htmlString = `<div class="event"> Event:${event.name</div>`;`
 you can use  `htmlString += `<div class="event"> Event: ${event.name}</div>`;` if the endpoint returns incremental data